# MVC4 new bundling/minification feature

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

I can't seem to get the new bundling/minification feature to work in my project.  I have this in my _Layout.cshtml.

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/" + ViewBag.SiteEntity.LayoutName + "/css/css")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this gives me the link href="/Content/themes/FixedLayout21/css/css" rel="stylesheet" which is the correct path, but its not displaying in the browser.  Any iodeas?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I didn't see this on ScottGu's blog.  I added BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles(); and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close out the question, add the following to the Application_Start() method of global.asax.

```
BundleTable.Bundles.EnableDefaultBundles();
```

Comment: This line isn't needed any more starting with ASP.NET 4.5